# Visual studio code launches chrome with no extensions or autofill data

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I've recently started using chrome debugging for visual studio code on an angular project.

I've followed all the configuration steps described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) and I'm able to successfully launch chrome against localhost, place breakpoints on VS Code and debug my code from there.

The issue is that the instance of chrome that VS Code launches does not have any of my chrome extensions, no auto fill information available and maybe even more things are missing.

Here is my `launch.json`code:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

How may I configure VS Code to launch a chrome instance with everything that I would usually have available on chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling for some time, I've found a way to make it work. I've modified my launch config to also set `userDataDir` field to `false`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "userDataDir": false
    }
  ]
}
```

This will open chrome with all extensions enabled and autofill data available. Still, **this only works if there is no chrome instance currently running.**