# How to debug React App from VSCode with enabled extensions in the browser

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have React app running locally on localhost:3000. I configured VSCode to debug app in MS Edge and Google Chrome also. I can launch browsers from VSCode debugger. Sometimes I launch Chrome and sometimes Edge. But the problem is with browser extensions. Launched browsers have resetted settings, and no extensions are present, for example React Developer Tools. I want to inspect React Components from this extension. Now I must launch manually browser card with url localhost:3000 and inspect components, but I haven't debugger attached for inspecting breakpoints in the same time.

Comment: This has worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858858/visual-studio-code-launches-chrome-with-no-extensions-or-autofill-data